# Don't filters violate the a class' local variables visibility rules?

Tags: oop

Pressume I have a class:

```
class TestClass
{
    protected $handle;
}
```

and in that class, I decide that my `$handle` will be set by a filter, in the constructor:

```
class TestClass
{
    private $handle
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->handle = apply_filters( 'handle_filter', '' );
    }
}
```

Have I not just violated / nullified the `private` statement that should dictate that, under no circumstance `$handle` should change, no matter what inheritance is done. But, due to it being a filter, it can change from anywhere so integrity is not assured.

In other words, `private` ensures integrity throughout the lifecycle of a class, whether it inherits or it's inherited, `protected` would allow for extension only by classes that work with my class.

It's really a contradiction and the `private` statement is useless then or am I missing something?

---

The other end of the stick is "this variable can change in many ways up until it reaches my class, once it reaches my class, it cannot change anymore and it will remain so unless the parent class decides it wants to change it", so, this could be a non-issue.

If this is true, then filters are violators of visibility until they're not, kind of like when kids do what they want but once the parents arrived home, they're silent?

Comment: What does filters have to do with anything here? `apply_filters` could be any other function and the behaviour would be the same. I don't see how filters are special here. Regardless, `private` has nothing to do with whether or not the variable can change, it just means where it can be changed or read _from_.

Comment: @JacobPeattie That's what I meant (for your second part of the question), sorry, didn't word it correctly, if you'd suggest an edit, I'd be glad to accept it. But that's the thing (as for your first part): `apply_filters` allows what's supposed to be a private variable to be read / changed from everywhere.

Comment: So would using *any* function to set the value.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Exactly, but that's the thing - there's no setters, at all. In a non WordPress environment (unless it imitates filters, which are more or less global states), this could be considered an anti-pattern because you enter a loophole of not knowing where things change and by who they're changed in an elegant manner and that's my question - is this an anti-pattern / bad thing? I understand it's opinion-based to a degree but I feel the question is important - if you're trying to build a reliable system, this clashes with it.